# hornetq static clustering configuration

Tags: hornetq

i am trying to set-up a hornetq cluster using static clustering with two machines (say x.my-domain.com and y.my-domain.com) where there will be two instances of hornetq servers running. I am going to use the default configuration as given in ~/hornetq-2.2.5.Final/examples/jms/clustered-static-discovery/server{0,1}/hornetq-configuration.xml, one in each of the servers. I hope this would work as they already have different connector-port/ connector-name/ connector-ref in the configuration files under server0/ server1.

Also, under the configuration directory, there are several default dir/ files (jboss-as-4, jboss-as-5, ra.xml, stand-alone). Should i delete all of them and put only hornetq-configuration.xml as mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0):

When starting a hornetq node you should pass a configuration directory you want to use. It is by default set to following relative (to the **run.sh** or **run.bat** starting script) `../config/stand-alone/non-clustered`.

You can copy the example and place it anywhere you want, but then you need to run hornetq and passing configuration directory location as a first parameter, i.e. `./run.sh ../config/my-custom-config`.